# HTML date field setting max date with JS

Tags: javascript, forms

When entering a first date in form field with ID `dateInput` and running the function `showEndDate` the `inputDate + 21 days` is outputted to the console successfully but no maximum is being set on form field with ID `end_date`.
What is **incorrect with my use** of `setAttribute("max", inputDate)`. ?

I have tested entering a fixed value such as `setAttribute("max", '2021-10-31')` and this works **31st Oct** does get set correctly as the upper max value in the date field ! :( :S

```
// Declare values for use in functions
    let dateInput = document.getElementById("dateInput");
    var endDateInput = document.getElementById("end_date");

// Shows the end date field
    function showEndDate() {
      var inputValue = dateInput.value;
      var inputDate = new Date(inputValue);
      if(inputValue != "") {
        document.getElementById("panel").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        alert("Date cannot be blank");
      }
      inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 21);
      console.log(inputDate);
      endDateInput.setAttribute("max", inputDate);
    }
```

```
<input id="dateInput" type="date" name="manufacture_one" required ></div>
```

also end date:

```
<input id="end_date" type="date" name="holiday_end_date" >
```

Comment: _"`max`: The latest date to accept. If the value entered into the element occurs afterward, the element fails constraint validation. If the value of the `max` attribute **isn't a possible date string in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`**, then the element has no maximum date value."_

Comment: `inputDate.toString()` does not return a string in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: thanks Andreas `inputDate.toString()` does NOT return `yyyy-mm-dd` great to know thanks ! So how can I return the SQL date format required please ? post as answer and i'll accept it.  thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Jeanclaude See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date and any of dozens of others.

Comment: great thanks @T.J.Crowder i've gone with `inputDate = inputDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
endDateInput.setAttribute("max", inputDate);`

Answer (score 0):

`inputDate` is a **`Date`**, but attribute values are strings. So the date is being converted to string using the default `toString` method, which doesn't provide the date in the format expected of the `max` attribute.

You'll need to format it explicitly. There are lots of ways to do it, one of which (**if** you want the date in UTC [and yes, it matters even just for dates without times]) is `inputDate.toString().substring(0, 10)`. But again, that'll be in UTC. If you want local time, you'll have to format it another way. There are **lots** of examples of formatting dates here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) for example) and on the web.

Comment: thanks T.K.Crowder so i've tried adding `inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 21);
      console.log(inputDate);
      inputDate.toString().substring(0, 10);
      endDateInput.setAttribute("max", inputDate);` but this hasn't resolved my issue.

Comment: You're still using the date object, not the string that `toString().substring(0, 10)` returns.